# CS Cart Vendor specific discount

Tags: cs-cart

Here's what I need:
I need to setup Vendor-discount values for product purchase in cs-cart multivendor(4.0) setup on my server.
Can somebody guide me regarding this ?
Thanks in advance !!!

Vivek Shah

Answer (score -1):

There is some sample code here:
http://forum.cs-cart.com/topic/34865-vendor-promotions-a-free-partial-implementation/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. This is a [questions and answers site](http://stackoverflow.com/about), not a link collection. Please include relevant content in your answer, not just a link to where the content may be. The link is nice to have in addition for reference or for further information. For more tips, see [How to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).